# Reverting the view SDL

Tags: opengl, game-mechanics, sdl, graphics-programming

So in my SDL application, which  I setup for OpenGL, if I were to do the following code:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2i(0, 0);
glVertex2i(50, 0);
glVertex2i(50, 50);
glVertex2i(0, 50);
glEnd();
```

The quad shows up on my right hand side of my screen. I tried to use *glOrtho* but that didn't work for some reason. What happend?

Comment: I would guess it's because the OpenGL co-ordinate system is far from intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be because you are treating (0, 0) as the bottom left; in OpenGL (0, 0) is the center of the screen.

To say this is counter-intuitive is silly, it is fully your opinion to say so.

I presume you have a 50x50 window you are trying to fill?

**To get your desired behaviour you would need the following:**

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2i(-1, -1); // bottom left
glVertex2i( 1, -1); // bottom right
glVertex2i( 1,  1); // top right
glVertex2i(-1,  1); // top left
glEnd();
```

**and a diagram**

*(-1, 1)--------------------------(1, 1)*

*----------------------------------------*

*-----------------(0,0)-----------------*

*----------------------------------------*

*(-1,-1)------------------------(1, -1)*